# Where clause in SQL for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this simple SQL query in ASP.NET MVC that works fine:

```
<%var JobsListQuery = from jobsListVariant in Model.ListOfJobsListVariant
                      orderby jobsListVariant.VariantId
                      select jobsListVariant;%>
```

But I want to now filter it further with a 'where' clause just before the 'orderby' but it's not working and I can't get the syntax correct. Anybody have any ideas?

```
where jobsListVariant.VariantId like '%morning%'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is that that isn't SQL, it's LINQ, and LINQ doesn't support the `like` operator. You need to use Contains.

```
where jobsListVariant.VariantId.Contains("morning")
```

You are correct that it goes before the orderby.

```
<% var JobsListQuery = from jobsListVariant in Model.ListOfJobsListVariant
      where jobsListVariant.VariantId.Contains("morning")
      orderby jobsListVariant.VariantId
      select jobsListVariant; %>
```